# Import csv files into pandas and merge into one df (with unequal count of levels in column)

Tags: pandas, merge, assign

I am able to merge two dataframes manually, but i can't figure it out, how to automate the process.

[image]

This merge could be done as follows:

```
new_df = df1.assign(index_count=df1.groupby('Step_ID').cumcount())\
            .merge(df2.assign(index_count=df2.groupby('Step_ID').cumcount()),
                   on=['Step_ID', 'index_count'], how='outer')\
            .sort_values(['Step_ID', 'index_count'])\
            .drop('index_count', axis=1)

print(new_df)
```

It works manually great, but i would like to read all csv files in a folder and merge them (with the code above) automatically.

In order to append all CSV's i have tried the following:

---

Here is the upload of two csv files: https://github.com/pit9921/test

In case that read_csv of uploaded files does not work, here are the both df's, which could be stored localy:

```
import pandas as pd  
 
data = {'Step_ID': ["Step1", "Step1", "Step1", "Step2", "Step2", "Step3", "Step3"],    
        'value_01': [2, 2.3, 2.2, 0, 0, 5, 5.2]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df1.to_csv('df1.csv', index=False)

data = {'Step_ID': ["Step1", "Step1", "Step1", "Step1", "Step2", "Step2", "Step2", "Step3", "Step3", "Step3"],    
        'value_02': [2.3, 2.5, 2.1, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 5.1, 5.6, 5.8]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is **the solution** from an user (i guess Henry Ecker), who deleted his posts. Sorry for my amateurism and a big thank to you.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\xxx' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    dfs.append(df.set_index(['Step_ID', df.groupby('Step_ID').cumcount()]))

merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
```